# How to work with many to many relationships in ASP.NET Core MVC web app

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, onion-architecture

I am creating a restaurant app, I have the entity `Dish` and the entity `Ingredients`, both of which should be related so that I can know what ingredients I have in each dish, my idea was to make a joined entity with both `DishId` and `IngredientId`, and that table will handle every dish - ingredient combination.

Here is what the entity looks like:

```
public class DishIngredient : AuditableBaseEntity
{
    public int DishId { get; set; }
    public Dish Dish { get; set; }
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a method in my controller that sends me every Dish and the corresponding ingredients of the dish using a navigation property `List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }` to my `DishViewModel` but I'm not really sure if that's the correct implementation.

```
public class DishViewModel
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public double Price { get; set; }
     public int People { get; set; }
     public string Category { get; set; }
     public List<Ingredients> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I am not really sure about how to get the dishes with the ingredients together.

I have tried to use the Include method in EF Core to get the `DishIngredients` table so that then I can get the `Ingredients` table but that does not seem to be sending any data (I think that the lack of any filtering is causing the `DishIngredients` table to be sent null)

```
public async Task<List<Dish>> GetDishesWithIngredients()
{
     var result = _dbContext.Dishes
                            .Include(di => di.DishIngredients)                
                            .ToList();
     return result;            
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework is not ASP.NET Core.

Comment: _"my idea was to make a joined entity with both DishId and IngredientId"_ - don't forget quantity/mass/volume of ingredients too.

Comment: What is `AuditableBaseEntity`? I'll warn you that OOP inheritance does not play-nice with EF - or RDBMS in general. And if you want auditable data, you should do it at the DB-level, not the application-level (e.g. use Temporal Tables or CDC - as doing it only in EF means that changes made without EF won't be captured).

Comment: 1- I know that Entity Framework is not ASP.NET Core, what I meant to say is that I'm creating an ASP.NET Core app using the EF Core package.

2- The idea was that, making a joined entity with DishId and IngredientId as a conjoined PK / FK's I would just add relevant information to both in their own tables and just the relationship in the DishIngredient table.

3- Don't worry too much about AuditableBaseEntity, this is not a professional project.

Comment: Would be dumb to assume otherwise. I am asking about a relatively low difficulty problem like many to many relationships, I thought It was given that I am a beginner in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that I am not really sure about how to get the dishes
> with the ingredients together.

You may follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-navigations-to-join-entity):

Add nevigation property in Dish entity and Ingredient entity:

```
public class Dish
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? DishProp { get; set; }
    .....

    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = default!;

    public List<DishIngredient> DishIngredients { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? IngredientProp{ get; set; }
    .....

    public List<Dish> Dishes { get; set; } = default!;
    public List<DishIngredient> DishIngredients { get; set; } = default!;
}


public class DishIngredient 
{
    public int DishId { get; set; }
    public Dish Dish { get; set; } = default!;
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

configure as below in dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Dish>().HasMany(x => x.Ingredients).WithMany(y => y.Dishes).UsingEntity<DishIngredient>();
    
 }
```

Read Dishs with Ingredients:

```
var result = await _context.Dish.Include(x => x.Ingredients).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I love you random internet person.